# Is there a word for being memorable?

Tags: single-word-requests

I provide paint job service for homes, a custom paint job that only I provide, none of my competitors do this kind of paint job. For this service I am looking for a tagline.
In the tagline I want to say **because of my paint job people will remember your home**
So your home becomes memorable but if I want to say it in short like **Get ___**

Comment: You mean `deja vu` ?, can you use it in a sentence ?

Comment: Neither of your first two sentences are grammatical - and I am quite confused as to what you are saying. Can you provide a sentence with a blank space for the word you require?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a slogan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The straight-forward word is **recognized**.

[**recognize** verb

to know someone or something because you have seen or heard him or her or experienced it before](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/recognize)

The (somewhat narrow) distinction from *remembered* (or the similar *recalled*) — and the reason it fits the questions — is that something recognized has been seen (or heard) previously, whereas something remembered may be anything committed to memory — a piece of poetry one has learned, the derivation of the Pythagoras theorem etc.

N.B.
Also spelt *recognise* in British English from the second half of the 20th century.

Comment: I had both those word in mind but the dictionary got me confused. Can you please look at the edited question and see which of these two words fits better ?

Comment: I don’t normally write advertising copy without payment, but “Be recognized!” Is hardly worth charging for.

Comment: lol I just saw it somewhere and got curious.

Answer (score 1):

You can be known or recognized as the person who reads on the bus every day, but those don't carry the same meaning that you're after.

I would say that [**famous**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/famous) is more precise than anything else.

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **1 a** : widely known
>   // a restaurant famous for its French cuisine

To be *famous* is not just to be known, but to also be acclaimed and lauded—like a celebrity. The title of a once-popular TV show was [*Lifestyles of the Rich and Famous*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifestyles_of_the_Rich_and_Famous).

---

For a tagline, I would use *get*. It would be more idiomatic as the following:

> Become *famous*.